# ::selection padding on css possible?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

The System is using Bootstrap CSS and somehow I could not find why the selected text is aligned on top and there are no any classes or ids. Adding "vertical-align" did not help me.

Any idea why is that?

[image]

[image]

Comment: short answer **no**, more details here -> https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/s/selection/

Comment: add line-height to your parent element and see if it will remove the extra padding.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)